# Split up a memorystream into bytarray

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, memorystream, chunks

Im trying to split up a memorystream into chunks by reading parts into a byte array but i think i have got something fundamentally wrong. I can read the first chunk but when i try to read rest of memorystream i get index out of bound even if there are more bytes to read. It seems that the issue is the size of the receving byte buffer that need to be as large as the memorystrem. I need to convert it into chunks as the code is in a webservice.

Anyone knows whats wrong with this code

fb.buffer is MemoryStream

```
  long bytesLeft = fb.Buffer.Length;
                fb.Buffer.Position = 0;
                int offset =0;
                int BUFF_SIZE = 8196;


                while (bytesLeft > 0)
                {
                    byte[] fs = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];

                    fb.Buffer.Read(fs, offset, BUFF_SIZE);
                    offset += BUFF_SIZE;
                    bytesLeft -= BUFF_SIZE;
                }
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to use `Read` here; just use `GetBuffer` and then in the loop, `Buffer.BlockCopy` the data from the backing buffer to the smaller buffers

Answer (score 2):

`offset` here is the offset **into the array**. It should be zero here. You should also be looking at the **return** value from `Read`. It is not guaranteed to fill the buffer, **even if** more data is available.

However, if this is a `MemoryStream` - a better option might be `ArraySegment<byte>`, which requires no duplication of data.

Comment: Thanks , stupid misstake. Seen this 'not guaranteed to fill buffer' before and always wondered what it means. Is the read operation some type of random process or?

Comment: @klashagelqvist On a `NetworkStream` it pretty much is. If not enough data has arrived yet to fill the buffer, but the connection hasn't been closed either, it will only fill part of the buffer with the available data, and return. But I don't think such partial reads can happen on a MemoryStream.

Comment: @klashagelqvist indeed, as CodeInChaos notes, MemoryStream probably won't bite you here, but that is an implementation detail. I strongly suggest following the formal Stream API, which *only* guarantees "none" or "some"

Answer (score 2):

Please look at [this code for `Stream.Read` from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) from a glance - you shouldn't be incrementing `offset` - it should always be zero.  Unless, of course, you happen to know for a fact the exact length of the stream in advance (therefore you would create the array the exact size).

You should also always grab the amount of bytes read from `Read` (the return value).

If you're looking to split it into 'chunks` do you mean you want *n* 8k chunks?  Then you might want to do something like this:

```
List<byte[]> chunks = new List<byte[]>();
byte chunk = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
int bytesRead = fb.Buffer.Read(chunk, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
while(bytesRead > 0)
{
  if(bytesRead != BUFF_SIZE)
  {
    byte[] tail = new byte[bytesRead];
    Array.Copy(chunk, tail, bytesRead);
    chunk = tail;
  }
  chunks.Add(chunk);
  bytesRead = fb.Buffer.Read(chunk, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
}
```

Note in particular that the last chunk is more than likely not going to be exactly `BUFF_SIZE` in length.